# How to Post multiple image using OkHttpClient in android studio java?

Tags: java, android, api, okhttp

I need to send multiple files from android app

I have already succeeded sending the single file but I need to send multiple

> my request body

```
    RequestBody form = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("user_id", user_id)
            .addFormDataPart("title", title)
            .addFormDataPart("description", description)
            .addFormDataPart("price", price)
            .addFormDataPart("offer_price", offer_price)
            .addFormDataPart("amenities", amenities)
            .addFormDataPart("type", type)
            .addFormDataPart("status", "1")
            .addFormDataPart("file", user_id + ".JPG", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, bytarray))
            .addFormDataPart("file1", user_id + "1.JPG", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, bytarray1))
            .addFormDataPart("file2", user_id + "2.JPG", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, bytarray2))
            .build();
```

> post url

```
String url = path.URL + path.CREATE_POST_API;
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(form)
                .build();
```

> Okhttp execute

```
    try (Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
       // System.out.println(response.body().string());
        Log.d("runPost: ", response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is there any errors?

Comment: no errors but it pos the one picture